# How to calculate the different combinations of an N×M grid with 3-valid values

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, python

I have 3 valid values: a,b,c I can insert them in a N×3 grid in such a way that no row or column contains cells that are the same values. How can I calculate the number of valid patterns that can be created using N rows?

For example, if N = 4, the total number of valid pattern is 296490.
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
def countPatterns(n):

    dp1, dp2 = 6,6
    mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
    
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        dp1, dp2 = (dp1 * 3 + dp2 * 2) % mod, (dp1 * 2 + dp2 * 2) % mod
    return (dp1 + dp2) % mod
```

When N = 4, the output should be 174 but I'm getting 54.

Comment: Also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952172/permutation-combination-question-3n-board  Where does $174$ come from?  Posting code with no comments is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: @RossMillikan his answer throws an error. For an input of `9`, the output is `2640599939550` when it should be `599921070`.